# constant volume and surface area

Tags: logic, volume

While reading about surface tension,i got to know that water drops are spherical because for a given volume the sphere have minimum area.I thought about proving this fact (for a given volume,,sphere have minimum surface area) but now i understand the complexity of situation as I don't know how to even approach to prove it..

I just want this problem to be solved.I shall be highly obliged if someone of you give me a hind for approach to solve this question.
thanks

Comment: i suggest you read CALCULUS OF VARIATIONS. That should help you all the way.

Comment: from a specific book or from internet??

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765813/isoperimetric-inequality-on-the-sphere-via-calculus-of-variations

Comment: Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000019-QINU.60.22.27.7F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a trivial result. You can read:
http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/isoperim/isop.pdf

Comment: Also http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/mbenders/cofv.pdf